# Is there a way to programmatically select a node in a VirtualTreeView?

Tags: delphi, virtualtreeview

I need to select a specific node in VirtualTreeview programmatically, but I don't
find any method to do so. Anybody could help with a solution?

Comment: `VirtualTree.Selected[NodeOfYourChoice] := True;`

Comment: Presumably preceded by `VirtualTree.ClearSelection;`

Comment: ...if you use multiselect.

Comment: Wow, that was fast !

Comment: See also [How to select all root or all child nodes in VirtualStringTree?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12142258/576719).

Comment: Interestingly this changes visually the focus in the tree but focusednode remains the same...

Comment: Uhn... I got this. Changing the focusednode to the one seems to work... [code]VirtualTree.focusednode:=NodeSelected

Answer (score 6):

Select nodes like this:

```
VirtualTree.Selected[Node] := True;
```

If you have a multi-select tree then precede this by clearing any existing selection:

```
VirtualTree.ClearSelection;
```

Comment: This worked for me to select the node but later in the code I am attempting to grab the .FocusedNode but this is nil. Is there something else I can do to 'focus' the node also? The node seems to be focused when I actually click the node but not when doing it programatically using .selected[Node] := true.